# The message in trigger action not displayed when using before insert trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

check the code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPTRIG1
BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE DETAILS ARE ABT TO ADD
END;
```

Trigger created.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('ANIL',50,'MATHUR');
```

1 row created.

in the above mentioned code i have created a trigger which displays a message before inserting any record in table . but the message is not displaye .

can anyone help me .

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

You have to turn on output to SQL*PLUS

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
```